# CORS issue with api domain versus local domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, cors

I'm having the following CORS issue:

With Grunt I emulate my local environment `development-mydomain.com.br:9000`. It tries to access a remote API with the name `api-test.mydomain.com.br`. I have CORS issue with this.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api-test.mydomain.com.br/auth.php.
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'http://test.mydomain.com.br' that is not equal to the supplied
>   origin. Origin 'http://development-mydomain.com.br:9000' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

I also have a test enviroment `http://test.mydomain.com.br` which then works fine. Why is the header `http://test.mydomain.com.br` and not `http://api-test.mydomain.com.br` ?

Here is the `cors.php` file in my domain `http://api-test.mydomain.com.br` :

```
<?
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://test.mydomain.com.br");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://development-mydomain.com.br:9000");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE');
?>
```

**UPDATE**: got it working via https://stackoverflow.com/a/7454204/1147504

Comment: **UPDATE**: Since I can use PHP, got it working via http://stackoverflow.com/a/7454204/1147504

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
> header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://test.mydomain.com.br");
> header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://development-mydomain.com.br:9000");
> ```

Don't set the header multiple times. Set it once, to the value you actually want.

Comment: ok.. so how to make it work with development.mydomain and test.mydomain at the same time?

Comment: You use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` or `*`